# How to Save CCSprite as PNG

Tags: ios4, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, object-code

I created CCSprite and add it to the main view.
Then I want to see the sprite image, so I saved it to PNG
But lots of them doesn't saved correctly.
Only show white background.
I can't know the reason, and also found some articles via Google, but they didn't help me at all.
How can I solve this?

```
CCSprite *sprite = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name] rect:CGRectMake(startx, starty, w, h)] retain];

float drawX = x, drawY = y; 

CGSize size = [sprite contentSize];

int nWidth = size.width;
int nHeight = size.height;
nWidth *= scale;
nHeight *= scale;
drawX = drawX + nWidth/2;
drawY = drawY - nHeight/2;

ConvertCoordf(&drawX, &drawY);
drawY -= nHeight;
[sprite setScale:scale];
[sprite setPosition:ccp(drawX, drawY)];
[_mainLayer addChild:sprite];

CCRenderTexture* render = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:sprite.contentSize.width height:sprite.contentSize.height];    
[render begin];
[sprite visit];
[render end];    
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString  *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"new%d.png",i]];
i++;
[render saveBuffer:pngPath format:kCCImageFormatPNG];

[sprite release];
```

Comment: I'm not sure on the purpose of your code. Why are you trying to save the sprite to file when you are reading it from a file in the first place?

Comment: I also need an answer to this question. I applies opengl/shader effects to a ccsprite and now need to save it as a PNG.

Comment: [sprite setPosition:ccp(size.width/2.0f, size.height/2.0f)]; If you don't put the sprite inside the CCRenderTexture, you won't be able to see it.

Comment: This question ought to be re-opened, it's still relevant. Jay's answer is correct, FWIW.

Comment: Why this question should be closed??? Anyway, use CCRenderTexture and its method saveToFile().